# How to make LibreOffice Calc to connect points in a holed series chart with lines?

Tags: charts, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I've got a time series data table with one function (row) value available for every month and the second for every 3rd month (every quarter), having holes (empty cell values) for every 2nd and 1st months of a quarter.

When I try to make a chart, I can only draw a bar or a point chart, but I want the actual data points to be interconnected with lines visually filling the gaps.

How to achieve this in LibreOffice 3.6?

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure you've selected a **chart type** that allows for drawing lines: `Area`, `Line`, `XY (Scatter)` or `Columns and Lines`.

Now, create your chart as usual. After you've finished it, do a single-click on the line of the incomplete data series (the data points now should be green). Now, do a right-click on that line, and from the context menu, select "**`Format Data Series`**".

In the "`Format Data series`" dialog, under "`Plot Options`", **select "Continue line"**. Other Options are: "`Leave gap`" and "`Assume Zero`":

[image: Format Data Series]

Comment: If I choose a line chart style (not points-and-line), it just draws nothing, so, nothing to click at.

Comment: What about inserting some dummy data to get a line, modify it, and remove the dummy data afterwards?